# Sequence number field with concurrent writes

Tags: sql, entity-framework, aws-lambda, entity-framework-core

Imagine a rail track, and my goal is to store every railcar that exists on that track. Each railcar has a position. Say there are 100 railcars on the track, so each railcar object would have a TrackPosition from 1-100.

That is essentially what we are doing right now, with a Track having child Railcars, and each Railcar has an integer TrackPosition.

When a new railcar is added, we simply take the # of cars in the track + 1 to save the position of the new car.

We are running into issues in a few different areas:

- We would like to add cars concurrently using AWS Lambda. This presents a problem as two functions could hit the line of logic that calculates "total cars on track + 1" at the same time. When they go to save, both cars would have the same position. Locking that bit of code is not possible within AWS Lambda (as far as I can tell from what I've read). We've resolved this for the time being by setting the Lambdas to fire synchronously (concurrency set to 1), obviously not ideal for performance.
- We would like to add a car into the middle of a track. This would involve taking any car with a greater position and incrementing them all. Not difficult to write some code to do this, but..

I'm wondering if I'm missing something fundamental within SQL that can achieve what I am after in a less error-prone way. The way I'm doing it seems naive. I've looked into Sequences, but I'm not sure if they would solve my concurrency issue.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. We are using Entity Framework Core 2 with SQL Server.

Comment: Check out Tally tables.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/benjamin/2018/02/06/sql-tip-the-tally-table/

Comment: so, I would leverage Step Functions w/ some retry logic in here. so, the steps would be: 1. generate ID (this lambda knows the state); 2. Perform logic; 3. if fail bc of non unique, go back to #1.